# Firebase stored data with ${res.user.uid} instead of userid

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Firebase stored data with `${res.user.uid}` instead of userid .Please advise solution how to store user with userid

```
try{
  const res= await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username,password)
  this.afstore.doc('users/${res.user.uid}').set({
    username
  })

  this.user.setUser({
    username,
    uid:res.user.uid
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) but instead of using back-tips you use normal single quotes.

As explained in the doc:

> Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick character
>   instead of double or single quotes.